# How to let "Windows" detects the changes (Rename, Move or Delete) which I've done by my program to some files recently?

Tags: vb.net, file, contextmenu, rename, undo

Windows displays **"Undo Rename"**, "Undo Delete" or "Undo Move" in the system Context Menu since you do any of those recent changes to some file!

I have created a program which rename specific file chosen by the user, using `My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile` method in VB.net.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Test.txt", "SecondTest.txt")
```

But "Windows" couldn't detect the changes.

It's not to give this option **"Undo Rename"** in my program, but to let "Windows" detects the changes to give an option to Undo them via the system Context Menu!

Answer (score 0):

It is not "Windows" that is tracking that change it is the "File Explorer" program (it tracks changes that are made from within *that* program).

I don't think there will be any way to tell File Explorer that you have made a change to a file and add the undo action to its list.